# Persist cache ticket version 4.2.0

Tags: alfresco, opencmis

With the version 4.2.0 it is still possible persist the cache of the server?. I´m using tickets to authenticate users on openCMIS, but after restart the Alfresco server all tickets are gone.
Any idea how to make that still working?. Or other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. They have also faced same challanges.

https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/general/non-technical-alfresco-discussion/alfresco-restart-breaks-url-tickets-09132011-0345

https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/repository-services/tomcat-sessions-and-alfresco-tickets-it-same

Comment: I already read it. Problem is that those guys was using an older version of Alfresco where ehcache was part of the core. But not anymore.